# Re-use a plan ID multiple times for different price models

Tags: braintree

I'm working on a software-tool with payable features. I'm planning to use braintree to handle the payment part but at the moment it's only possible to create plans using the web UI.

Since the prices of my features vary depending on the country, I was thinking that I could simply create a plan `xyzd` and associate that with a feature:

```sql
INSERT INTO tool_feature (billing_plan_id, name) VALUES ('xyzd', 'Basic feature');

SET @basicFeatureId = 1;
```

and for another table which defines the prices for each country I'd have:

```sql
SET @germany = 1;
SET @italy= 2;

INSERT INTO tool_feature_billing_plan 
    (country_id, tool_feature_id, price) 
VALUES 
    (@germany, @basicFeatureId, 9.9); -- € 9.90 in Germany

INSERT INTO tool_feature_billing_plan 
    (country_id, tool_feature_id, price) 
VALUES 
    (@italy, @basicFeatureId, 19.9);  -- € 19.90 in Italy
```

This would allow me to do something like

```java
Long countryId = countryRepository.getCountryIdByAlpha2Code("de");
Float price = toolFeatureBillingPlanRepository.getPriceForCountry(countryId);

SubscriptionRequest request = new SubscriptionRequest()
    .id("new_id")
    .paymentMethodToken(paymentMethodToken)
    .price(new BigDecimal("" + price ))     // The price fetched from the database
    .planId(planId)
    .merchantAccountId(merchantAccountId);

Result<Subscription> result = gateway.subscription().update(
  subscriptionId,
  request
);
```

It seems that I can do that but the question is if it's a good idea to use a `Plan`/`Subscription` in such a way.

The main reason why I want to do that is because I don't want to create for all countries a plan and get all those IDs into my database etc.

This way I'd have one plan only for each feature and the rest would be handled on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The method you outlined above is correct and is a proper way of setting up `Subscriptions` with differing prices.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I wasn't sure if this is actually a good idea to do it like this!